# Scrapy Xpath construction producing empty brackets on dynamic site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to create a spider via scrapy to crawl a website and extract all links for specific stores. Ultimately, the spider would then use those store links to extract pricing information. The site is designed to break down store information into States and Regions. I have been able to extract all sub links for the States/regions, but I cannot seem to extract the specific information for the stores, that information being the store links.

I thought it had to do with the page not being loaded long enough for those store links to display. So I used selenium and delayed the timing by 20 seconds to allow appropriate time for the webpage to load. An example link would be https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/united-states/colorado and as you can see on the left hand side there is information for specific stores. A snippet using the inspect element yields the following HTML:

```
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="listing in listings" wm-listing-detail="" role="listing">
  <div ng-class="{unpublished: !listing.published}">
     <div class="listing feature-1 recreational dispensary" ng-     class="featureClassesFor(listing)" ng-click="setActiveMarker(listing)">
         <img class="avatar" ng-src="https://d2kxqxnk1i5o9a.cloudfront.net/uploads/avatars/dispensaries/5566/square_10569095_10152344322971376_2924814837799131094_n.jpg" src="https://d2kxqxnk1i5o9a.cloudfront.net/uploads/avatars/dispensaries/5566/square_10569095_10152344322971376_2924814837799131094_n.jpg"/>
         <div>
           <div class="name hovers">
              <a class="ng-binding" href="/dispensaries/organic-alternatives" role="listing url" ng-bind-html="listing.name">Organic Alternatives</a>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="address ng-binding">
         <div class="wm_map_inactive_rating">
```

I am looking to extract the information following the @href.

I have the following python code in the spider section of the scrapy project:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class scrapybotspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrapybot_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/united-states/colorado']
    delay = 20

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            StateCountyURL = response.xpath("//*[@id='wm-listings']/div/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/@href").extract()
            print StateCountyURL
```

This produces empty brackets and I have tried a number of different xpath constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start using [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits).

*Wait for the listings to be visible*. Working sample code for getting region links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/united-states/colorado')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.subregion a.region-ajax-link")))

for region in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.subregion a.region-ajax-link"):
    print region.get_attribute("href")

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/aspen-colorado
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/aurora
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/boulder
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/colorado-springs
...
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/other-co
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/summit-eagle-county
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/trinidad
```

And, similarly, for dispensaries:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dispensary div.name a")))

for dispensary in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.dispensary div.name a"):
    print dispensary.get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My last question is within those printed links, such as https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/boulder how can I extract the actual dispensary links, such as http://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/boulder-fresh-baked-dispensary I tried changing the CSS_selector to id.wm-listings a.ng-binding but to no avail. I apologize as I am sure you can tell I am fairly new to this! Thanks again this is terrific!

Comment: Nevermind figured it out! This has honestly taken me close to a week of tinkering around, and you answered it in minutes. Seriously unbelievably awesome! It worked with div.name.hovers a.ng-binding